# App MSI install hangs up on newly imaged PCs (Win10)

Tags: installation, windows-10, msi, windows-installer

I'm working on an issue that got kicked up to me from Tier 1. I have a proprietary app that's built into an MSI for deployment with a VBscript. I didn't do the build and I don't have access to the source files.

On PCs that have been online for a while, the install takes about 2 minutes and works without incident. On newly imaged PCs (with the same image!), the install just hangs and never completes. Some files and shortcuts are copied to relevant directories, but the installer doesn't complete and the app won't launch so some core piece is not making it through.

No relevant messages appear in the Windows event log. The install log always hangs up at this point:

```
InstallShield 6:55:08: Registering file c:\Program Files (x86)\[app]\[subfolder]\Lib\igVIEW15a.ocx (32-bit)
```

There are also several of these throughout the log:

```
InstallShield 6:55:08: Error loading ISBEW64.exe...File does not exist
InstallShield 6:55:01: Error extracting ISBEW64.exe from ISRegSvr.dll
```

I don't think the package or script is broken as it does work on most systems - just not on some. I'm thinking some kind of relevant core file or registry entry is missing. Google tells me these are InstallShield files, but their support forum is paywalled unfortunately so any easy fixes there are hidden from view.

I've been working on this for two days and I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run a processmonitor while the setup is running to see if a fail happen ?

Comment: I can; no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The problem is a newer Intel HD graphics driver that, for some inexplicable reason, breaks this MSI. The solution is to roll the Intel HD graphics driver back to 21.20.16.4590 or earlier.